# Get 2 posts per slide, Unslider, Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, categories, posts

I'm trying to get two posts per slide in my Wordpress theme. I get posts from the category "news" and want to display about 5 pages with 2 posts. At this moment it displays just one.

This is the code I've got at the moment.

```
<div class="banner">
                <ul>
                <?php   $logo = new WP_Query( array( 'category_name' => 'news', 'posts_per_page' => 10 ) ); ?>
                <?php   while ($logo->have_posts()) : $logo->the_post(); ?>
                <?php   $do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID; ?>

                    <li class="news-item col-1-1 no-pad">

                        <div class="description">
                            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4></a>
                            <p class="post-date">Gepubliceerd op: <?php echo get_the_date('d-m-Y'); ?></p>
                            <p><?php content(160); ?></p>
                        </div>

                        <a class="button-med" href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">Lees meer</a>

                    </li>

                <?php   endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
```